# Change window control buttons under Loki

Tags: release-loki, window-management, user-interface

How can i set windows control buttons to be windows style (minimize, maximize, close) via command line?

I've tried:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

and it works for Firefox but it doesn't affect elementary OS apps like Files, Music, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install tweaker for Loki:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Then Appearance - Windows Controls - Layout (Windows, OS X, etc)

For the latest version of elementary-tweaks look at the github repo https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks/

Comment: Note that elementary tweaks has been known in the past to totally trash systems.